# Now that the new TV season is coming, help us promote M&TV.SE!

Tags: discussion, promotion

Now that the new American television season is starting, there will be zillions of viewers tuning in to their favorite shows, and they'll have lots of questions. And since all those questions will be new, Movies and TV Stack Exchange will have as good a shot at having the best answer than any of those, you know, competitive sites. Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

What can you do to help?

1. As you watch new episodes, whenever you have questions, no matter how silly, **ask them here**. You're not the only one having that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself... and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself!
2. When answering questions, **do everything you can to overkill it**. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, analytical, ultra-clear guide with screenshots and quotes from the show. Help us have the best possible answer to questions that will come up!
3. If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, **edit it into shape**. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question into a full sentence, make edits that improve the question's findability/long-term value, anything that's necessary. Whip it into shape without losing the heart of the question itself!

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to questions about new and ongoing shows that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as the audiences for these shows grow. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Moves and TV Stack Exchange continues to have great answers like we have in the past, then we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

Get to asking!

Comment: Don't forget -- *Downton Abbey* comes back soon! And, a number of Asian dramas and Telanovelas will begin/end soon!

Comment: I'm waiting for Supernatural.

Comment: When is Breaking Bad coming back again?....oh yeah and Dexter!

Answer (score 4):

Also, another way to help the site is to participate in the Topic of the Week that's going on.  One way to participate is to give us suggestions on what to run and when.  Just because we have something scheduled for a certain time slot doesn't mean we're completely sold on running that topic, so if you can think of something better please let us know.